# Define a color scale given function values in R

Tags: r, colors

I'm trying to plot some polygons giving them a color.
The color is associated to a function value in the polygon. So I have 960 polygons, and 960 function values.

I want to associate this values to a color and to create a color scale. How can I create a color vector, having the function values?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this way, I think it's better. Maybe it will be useful for someone else in future

First, we need to use scaled values in [0,1] (this is very important)

```
ScaledX<-NULL
maximum<-max(X)
minimum<-min(X)
for (i in 1:length(X))
{
  ScaledX<-c(ScaledX,(X[i]-minimum)/(maximum-minimum))
}
```

Then we use `rgb` command:

```
Colors = rgb(1,ScaledX,0)

plot(..., col=Colors)
```

In rgb, the three values are levels of red, green and blue. Using this values, the lowest value of X will be red, and the highest yellow (similar to `heat.colors`).

It's possible to use the `rgb` code from 0 to 255, instead of 0 to 1, but i found this useful.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean somthing like this?

there are 950 horizontal lines in differenz colors

```
val <- (1:950)/950

from_col <- "red"
to_col <- "blue"

val_col <- colorRampPalette(c(from_col,to_col))(length(val))

plot(c(0,1), c(0,1))
for(i in seq_along(val_col)){
  abline(h=val[i], col=val_col[i])
}
```

[image]

Comment: In a new problem, I have to define colors proportional to the values of the vector. Your solution gives color for equidistant values, with `val_col <- colorRampPalette(c(from_col,to_col))(length(val))`. What should I do with non equidistant values?